# Wakatime action failing with "Resource not accessible by integration" error

Tags: github-actions, wakatime

Whenever I try to run workflow in GitHub actions this error appears:

[image: error]

In short I don't know what the problem is. I followed every instructions as per given in the official documentation [Official Documentation of WakaTime](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/waka-readme).

I want to fix that error, why is it happening?

> 445 CRITICAL 403 {"message": "Resource not accessible by integration", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents"}

Comment: Please include your workflow in your question.

Comment: actually, I solved it, there was an issue in GitHub actions where I didn't permit to read and write that's why this error was occurring

Comment: So, there was a `permissions` issue. Good to hear that you were able to solve it. Voting to close this as a typo. You may choose to remove it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

1. Go to the settings of the repository.
2. On the left menu, go to "actions".
3. Then click on "General", Here you'll get so many options.
4. Scroll down and give "read and write" permission under workflow." Permission.
   [Permission Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoYo6.png)
5. Then save it.